Gmail SMTP relay with postfix
I'm using mailcow-dockerized to send emails (verification emails and welcome emails).
I have many domains setup with mailboxes for each. I want all emails sent from noreply@domain1.com, and support@domain1.com to be relayed to Google workspace SMTP relay if the recipient email is not any of series of (@mail1.com, @mail2.com)
My postfix configuration files:
###file data/conf/postfix/extra.cf:
relayhost =
transport_maps = hash:/opt/postfix/conf/transport
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/opt/postfix/conf/sender_relay
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/opt/postfix/conf/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
smtp_helo_name=maildomain.com

###file data/conf/postfix/transport:
mail1.com smtp:
mail2.com smtp:

###File data/conf/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp-relay.gmail.com]:587 noreply@domain1.com:apppassword1
[smtp-relay.gmail.com-support]:587 support@domain1.com:apppassword2

###File data/conf/postfix/sender_relay:
noreply@domain1.com [smtp-relay.gmail.com]:587
support@domain1.com [smtp-relay.gmail.com]:587

Of course I had run postmap transport sasl_paswd sender_relay
The problem I'm facing is it's still relaying emails going to @mail1, @mail2

Do you want postfix to deliver mails to mail1.com and mail2.com locally instead of relay? If so then you can add the domains to mydestination.
Postfix will use local delivery for any domain in mydestination. There is no need to create a transport map for local delivery. If transport map is to be configured then using local instead of smtp will also work.
Also, format your question. It was difficult to understand without any fullstop or comma.
